# Team foundation server remains on loading

Tags: tfs

I've been in the middle of installing team foundation server 2010 while I had team foundation server 2012 installed. Suddenly in team server administration console all features in application-tier are loading... And everything is broken. I can't get through to team foundation projects either. Anybody help?????

Comment: You can't downgrade from TFS 2012 to TFS 2010, and you can't run two versions of TFS side-by-side on the same machine. What were you actually trying to accomplish here?

Answer (score 2):

You can't run two versions of TFS side by side on the same app tier, nor can you downgrade TFS.

Reinstall TFS 2012 and everything should be okay once you reconfigure the app tier.

Comment: What about all of my users/accounts?! They're deleted?!

Comment: Unless you somehow corrupted your TFS databases, everything is intact.

Comment: All that information is stored in the database for TFS, not the application.

Comment: Thanks dude. I'm gonna to install tfs 2012 again. Tnx.

Comment: How could I backup tfs before installing tfs 2012 once again? Is it sufficient to backup tfs databases from sql server management studio ?

Comment: Grab backups of all of the Tfs_ databases, that should be fine. I don't think your databases are in any danger, though.